# Fermat factorization method limit

Tags: algorithm, scheme

I am trying to implement Fermat's factorization (**Algorithm C** in *The Art of Computer Programming*, Vol. 2). Unfortunately in my edition (ISBN 81-7758-335-2), this algorithm is printed incorrectly. what should be the condition on factor-inner loop below? I am running the loop till y <= n [passed in as limit].

```
(if (< limit y) 0 (factor-inner x (+ y 2) (- r y) limit))
```

Is there anyway to avoid this condition altogether, as it will double the speed of loop?

```
(define (factor n) 
  (let ((square-root (inexact->exact (floor (sqrt n))))) 
    (factor-inner (+ (* 2 square-root) 1)
                  1 
                  (- (* square-root square-root) n)
                  n)))

(define (factor-inner x y r limit)
  (if (= r 0)
    (/ (- x y) 2)
    (begin 
      (display x) (display " ") (display y) (display " ") (display r) (newline)
      ;;(sleep-current-thread 1)
      (if (< r 0)
        (factor-inner (+ x 2) y (+  r x) limit)
        (if (< limit y)
          0
          (factor-inner x (+ y 2) (- r y) limit))))))
```

Comment: Why do you think the algorithm presented in the book is wrong?

Comment: If you think it is wrong, download the errata from Knuth and check for that page number. If you don't find it there, let him know.

Comment: @user49117: Because it is wrong. Here is the algo. as given in that edition of book. it won't even terminate they way it is given. 
C1: set x = 2sqrt(N)+1, y=1, r= (sqrt(N))^2-N // sqrt(N) is rounded to floor
C2: if r=0, done.
C3: set r=r+x, x+=2
C4: set r=r-y, y+=2
C5: return to c3 if r > 0, otherwise go to c2.

@Ian: Thanks! Will do that.

Comment: In the Third Edition, C5 says to return to C4 if r > 0, not C3.

Comment: @Jason: not in my edition [It is Third Edition, but Indian] though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(< limit y)` check is not necessary because, worst-case, the algorithm will eventually find this solution:

> *x* = *N* + 2
>
> *y* = *N*

It will then return 1.

Comment: Yes - that avoids the need for check. It will take very long for large prime numbers though!

Answer (score 1):

Looking through **Algorithm C**, it looks like the issue is with the recursion step, which effectively skips step C4 whenever `r < 0`, because `x` is not incremented and `r` is only decremented by `y`.

Using the notation of `a`, `b` and `r` from the 1998 edition of Vol. 2 (ISBN 0-201-89684-2), a Scheme version would be as follows:

```
(define (factor n) 
  (let ((x (inexact->exact (floor (sqrt n)))))
    (factor-inner (+ (* x 2) 1)
                  1
                  (- (* x x) n))))

(define (factor-inner a b r)
  (cond ((= r 0) (/ (- a b) 2))
        ((< 0 r) (factor-inner a       (+ b 2) (- r b)))
        (else    (factor-inner (+ a 2) (+ b 2) (- r (- a b))))))
```

**EDIT** to add: Basically, we are doing a trick that repeatedly checks whether

```
r <- ((a - b) / 2)*((a + b - 2)/2) - N
```

is 0, and we're doing it by simply tracking how `r` changes when we increment `a` or `b`. If we were to set `b` to `b+2` in the expression for `r` above, it's equivalent to reducing `r` by the old value of `b`, which is why both are done in parallel in step C4 of the algorithm. I encourage you to expand out the algebraic expression above and convince yourself that this is true.

As long as `r > 0`, you want to keep decreasing it to find the right value of `b`, so you keep repeating step C4. However, if you overshoot, and `r < 0`, you need to increase it. You do this by increasing `a`, because increasing `a` by 2 is equivalent to decreasing `r` by the old value of `a`, as in step C3. You will always have `a > b`, so increasing `r` by `a` in step C3 automatically makes `r` positive again, so you just proceed directly on to step C4.

It's also easy to prove that `a > b`. We start with `a` manifestly greater than `b`, and if we ever increase `b` to the point where `b = a - 2`, we have

```
N = (a - (a - 2))/2 * ((a + (a - 2) - 2)/2 = 1 * (a - 2)
```

This means that `N` is prime, as the largest factor it has that is less than `sqrt(N)` is 1, and the algorithm has terminated.

Comment: You are incrementing b, in both if and else of (< 0 r)?